# Как сделать отображение фрагмента на весь экран?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть Activity, содержащее кнопку,при нажатии на которую, нужно отобразить Fragment во весь экран. Как это реализовать? При помощи xml-разметки (активити,фрагмента) или что то вводят в сам java-класс?

Comment: Цель неясна. Что это будет? Новая "рабочая область", диалоговое окно? Текущий контент активити - не фрагмент?

Comment: Новая рабочая область, как новая активити

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас два варианта:

1. Делаем еще одно активити, в котором не вызываем setContentView в onCreate, вместо этого добавляем ваш фрагмент на активити. В первой активити при нажатии на кнопку вызываем второе активити через startActivity(intetn).
2. Содержимое вашего активити заворачиваем во фрагмент. При клике по кнопке вызываем в активити транзакцию, заменяющую один фрагмент другим